# SQL Server Script Database with Seed Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am creating an install script for a Sql server 2008 database using Tasks =>generate Scripts option. This works fine and creates a script including database,schema and seed data.

One problem I notice is that the A Stored procedure is created before the table it refers to is created and this gives error when creating the database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any built-in functionality for ordering the scripting, but you could split them up in separate scripts and control the order in which those are executed yourself.

For example, select just the tables and generate a tables create script, then select the sprocs and generate another script.